# How do I convert this IQueryable<Patient> to DbSet<Patient> ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-4.0

This should be straightforward but I'm getting tripped up on the line inside the IF block. The error on that line is

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable[Patient]' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet[Patient]'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)"

I tried appending a variety of extensions (`AsQueryable()`, `ToList()`, `AsEnumerable()`, etc) after `.Contains()` to no avail.

What am I missing here? This project is build using the MVC 4 Beta and EF4

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
{
    var patients = this.db.Patients;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        patients = patients.Where(p => p.LastName.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(patients.ToList());

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the question be "How do I convert this DbSet<Patient>  to IQueryable<Patient>" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declare patients explicitly as `IQueryable<Patient>`

```
IQueryable<Patient> patients = this.db.Patients;
```

Or call `AsQueryable` on it:

```
var patients = this.db.Patients.AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just change the type of `patients` to make this work:

```
IQueryable<Patient> patients = this.db.Patients;
```